# Pitch accent of ～ざる

Tags: verbs, pitch-accent

What is the resulting pitch accent when one appends ～ざる to 平板 (する, 言う, 寝る) and 起伏 (来る, 持つ, 食べる) verbs?

Intuitively, I would have assumed that the resulting word falls in the same class (平板／起伏) as the simplex, but not only do I come across both pitches for e.g. 行かざる on [Youglish](https://youglish.com/pronounce/%22%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%8B%E3%81%96%E3%82%8B%22/japanese), I was also corrected by a native speaker when I said 振らざる{LHHH} instead of 振らざる{LHHL}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-ざる always turns the word into nakatakagata. [○ざる]{LHL}, [○○ざる]{LHHL}, [○○○ざる]{LHHHL}, etc. This even applies to atamadaka verbs such as [持つ]{HL} (→[もたざる]{LHHL}) and [見る]{HL} (→[みざる]{LHL}).

Some suffixes force a certain accent type. For another example, -型 always heibanifies the original word.

Comment: I see we have [ある]{HL}, and the -ざる ending is a contraction of -ず + ある.  Is the resulting [○○ざる]{LHHL} etc. pattern due to the underlying [ある]{HL} pitch pattern?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Sorry, I know nothing about old accents.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi - Not sure if this means anything, but ある is [ある]{LH} in Kansai-ben but I think ざる is always [ざる]{HL}. The part before it can be all high or all low, though.